# Writing logs to a different file only for a particular flow

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I need to write to a different log file for a particular flow of code. This flow is not restricted to a single package and also uses utility classes which other classes also refer.

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, file ,sim

# Direct log messages to a log file
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=../log/main.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=10MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=30
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n


#log messages to a log file
log4j.appender.sim=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.sim.File=../log/custom.log
log4j.appender.sim.MaxFileSize=10MB
log4j.appender.sim.MaxBackupIndex=30
log4j.appender.sim.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.sim.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

With this everything is getting logged in both the logs despite me doing this in the Java class

```
private static Logger customLogger= Logger.getLogger("custom");
```

My scenario is that i need to write to that customLogger whenever i want in that flow of code. It is not restricted to single package this flow.

Comment: private static Logger customLogger= Logger.getLogger("sim"); This was in my Java class . The one on the question is incorrect

Comment: So you want to use "custom" appender in some of your classes, am I getting it right ?

Comment: Not a custom appender. May be i put it wrong. What i want is to log a particular flow of code in a different log. I dont mind how i achieve it . My above settings is logging everything in both logs.

Comment: What do you mean by a flow of code ? is it a set of classes ?

Comment: lets say class A , class B , class C.. My flow is A-B and then invokes a method in class C.. where class C has other methods utilized for other flows too. So A-B and in that particular method in C i want to write everything into a different log.

Comment: can you please update your post with the right name of your logger "sim" instead of "custom"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `getLogger(String name)` actually gets the logger bundled with the string you pass as an argument. This method is usually used with class names so you can retrieved the appenders configured with your class name.

If you haven't specified any in the `log4j.properties` which is your case then it uses the rootLogger with is configured with both your appenders and therefor it logs two times.

The way you can solve this is by declaring a logger with custom name and then get the logger with the name "sim" and bundel it with your sim appender.

Add the following the your `log4j.properties` and it will work :

```
log4j.logger.sim=INFO, sim
log4j.additivity.sim=false
```

However I don't recommend this way of handling logging because it can get very complex to reason about when your classes start using more than one logger.

Comment: This worked. From Java file i need to do getLogger("sim.ClassName") to log along with the class Name instead of just sim.